# Flutter DraggableScrollableSheet - how to expand/collapse programmatically

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm wondering if anyone knows/found a way to make Flutters' DraggableScrollableSheet expand/collapse programmatically. I'm using Flutters latest build from their Dev channel which allows me to wrap it in a

```
NotificationListener<DraggableScrollableNotification>
```

which I can then listen to the extend of how far the sheets is expanded / collapsed. However, I'm not clear on how I would be able to collapse an expanded sheet or vice versa.

Seems in the widget src file there's a

```
DraggableScrollableActuator
```

that exposes a static .reset but I don't know/or think of a way to make that work.

Answer (score 21):

Building on Pierre's answer I ended up implementing a workaround that allows me to use `DraggableScrollableActuator` to both collapse and expand the `DraggableScrollableSheet`.

You can use the `setState` method to change the value of `initialChildSize` and then use the `DraggableScrollableActuator.reset` method to either expand or collapse the sheet.

```
void toggleDraggableScrollableSheet() {
  if (draggableSheetContext != null) {
    setState(() {
      initialExtent = isExpanded ? minExtent : maxExtent;
    });
    DraggableScrollableActuator.reset(draggableSheetContext);
  }
}
```

Important thing to make this work is to provide a different `Key` for when the widget is collapsed and expanded. This will result in 2 instances of `_DraggableScrollableSheetState` - one that you will be able to reset to collapsed state and another that you will be able to reset to expanded state.

```
DraggableScrollableActuator(
  child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
    key: Key(initialExtent.toString()),
    minChildSize: minExtent,
    maxChildSize: maxExtent,
    initialChildSize: initialExtent,
    builder: draggableScrollableSheetBuilder,
  ),
)
```

*Edit:*

Working example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  static const List<Color> colors = [
    Colors.red,
    Colors.green,
    Colors.blue,
  ];

  static const double minExtent = 0.2;
  static const double maxExtent = 0.6;

  bool isExpanded = false;
  double initialExtent = minExtent;
  BuildContext draggableSheetContext;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: _buildBody(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: _toggleDraggableScrollableSheet,
      child: DraggableScrollableActuator(
        child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
          key: Key(initialExtent.toString()),
          minChildSize: minExtent,
          maxChildSize: maxExtent,
          initialChildSize: initialExtent,
          builder: _draggableScrollableSheetBuilder,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _toggleDraggableScrollableSheet() {
    if (draggableSheetContext != null) {
      setState(() {
        initialExtent = isExpanded ? minExtent : maxExtent;
        isExpanded = !isExpanded;
      });
      DraggableScrollableActuator.reset(draggableSheetContext);
    }
  }

  Widget _draggableScrollableSheetBuilder(
    BuildContext context,
    ScrollController scrollController,
  ) {
    draggableSheetContext = context;
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      controller: scrollController,
      child: Column(
        children: colors
            .map((color) => Container(
                  height: 200,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  color: color,
                ))
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide full working example? @gtrochimiuk

Comment: Thank you very much i was really stuck and was about to give up.

Comment: @gtrochimiuk I have used your solution. But the problem is the change is happing with a jerk in the UI. Is there a way I can do it smoothly?

Comment: Not that I know of. There is an open issue in the github repo with a request to add an `animateTo` method to the `DraggableScrollableActuator` that would solve the problem:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45009

Answer (score 13):

There's a new solution available - ready to use in stable channel.

With the use of new `DraggableScrollableController` you can now programatically show or hide the `DraggableScrollableSheet` with or without an animation.

```dart
class TestWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final controller = DraggableScrollableController();
  final minChildSize = 0.2;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DraggableScrollableSheet(
      controller: controller,
      minChildSize: minChildSize,
      builder: _buildBody(),
    );
  }

  void animatedHide() {
    controller.animateTo(
      minChildSize,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
      curve: Curves.easeOutBack,
    );
  }
}
```

Documentation available here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DraggableScrollableController-class.html

Comment: Even though this has been merged in November, it's still not in the stable release (currently flutter v `2.8.1.`) ‍♂️ I think it's gonna land in the next update, which will probably be in February or March.

Comment: it is in stable version

Answer (score 5):

You can reset the position of the `DraggableScrollableSheet` to its `initialChildSize`by using the `DraggableScrollableActuator`.
Therefore you need to have the `BuildContext`, which is given to you by the DraggableScrollableSheet builder-parameter.

For example, you can create a Button inside the `DraggableScrollableSheet`and call `DraggableScrollableActuator.reset(context);`

```
DraggableScrollableSheet(
  builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {

    return MaterialButton(
      onPressed: () {
        DraggableScrollableActuator.reset(context);
      },
    );

  },
)
```

If you want to reset the `DraggableScrollableSheet` from outside its build-function, you need to create a property of BuildContext, which can be used to save the `DraggableScrollableSheet` context into.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - this allows for "reset" but there seems to be no way I can figure out to programmatically control the height of the bottom sheet (e.g. expand / collapse to a certain height) or at least 'send' the sheet up to its maxHeight...

Comment: @Andre Yes thats right. I needed this for myself, because I open the sheet, load a text and then want to adjust the height accordingly to the needed height. I ended up copying the DraggableScrollableSheet and adjusting it to my need.

Comment: FWIW, I made a feature request to extend the DraggableScrollableSheet/Actuator API with this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45009.